# Oracle sql STRUCT creation taking too much time

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Java imports snippet:

```
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
```

PLSQL code snippet:

**one_user_type** :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE one_user_type ABCD IS OBJECT
(
   user_id    VARCHAR2(120),
   user_name VARCHAR2(120)
)
```

Java code snippet:

// Connection conn;

```
Object[] userObject1 = new Object[] {
                    "101", "peter" };

StructDescriptor userDescriptor = StructDescriptor
                    .createDescriptor("one_user_type", conn);


// The below line takes 2.5 seconds approx to execute.
```

**`STRUCT user1 = new STRUCT(userDescriptor, conn, userObject1);`**

---

*notes: ojdbc6.jar ; jdk1.6, Oracle 11g*

**Question** -  Any idea why is this taking too much time, and how to reduce it?

**Edit 1** in response to @Lalit Kumar B comments: 'too much time' is in relative to the actual query execution. The STRUCT is created to pass a Table of Records/Table of Objects to a PLSQL Procedure. The actual query execution takes just 93 milliseconds, where as UI waits for around 5 seconds when two such procedures are called, both of them taking Table of Objects and where we need to create STRUCT.
Hence 2.5 seconds is considered so much, and I like to finetune it. When I checked the execution time of other Java object construction, transformation, query execution etc, they are all very much low compared to this one STRUCT creation.
Considering my scenario where I really call 5 stored procedures, which takes Table of Objects as parameter, I make 5 different calls to create STRUCT for each of them, it totally takes around 7 seconds for just STRUCT creation. The idea is to call the procedures, get the result, put in a wrapper and send back to UI.

**Edit 2:[09/20]** To minimize the time, created a single procedure that takes a Table of Objects and acts as a wrapper that internally calls the 5 procedures. Hence from Java code, its just one stored procedure call. Still, STRUCT has to be created one time to feed as input to the wrapper procedure. On running multiple times, its observed that the STRUCT creation can go anywhere between 2 seconds to 8 seconds!!   Am I doing wrong in the way the STRUCT is created? I checked Oracle docs from the link provided below, but I couldn't figure out if i deviated.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Update: Creating STRUCT Objects and Descriptors
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/oraoot.htm

**Edit 3: Add-on to Solution[09/23]**
The accepted solution is ideal for storing a single object.In case of table of objects to be passed, the case apply as below:

PLSQL:

```
TYPE one_user_table_type IS TABLE OF one_user_type; // Table of Objects
```

Java:

```
UserType user = new UserType( "101", "Peter" );
ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
                    "ONE_USER_TABLE_TYPE", conn);
UserType[] userArray = { user };
Array users = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, userArray );
callableStatement.setArray(1, users);
```

Comment: `Too much time` cannot be technically compared with what you think a shorter time frame is. So, please post required details like elapsed time, execution plan etc. 2.5 seconds in real world is considered quite fast, perhaps twice you blink your eyes. But if you think otherwise, you need to provide the requested details.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, thanks, updated with edit comments

Comment: Ok, now you are a bit close to get an answer. But, I would like to know why PL/SQL is needed, how about plain SQL to give the result set back to UI? It will reduce the `context switching` between the two engines, PL/SQL and SQL.

Comment: And another important thing, is it a concurrent operation or isolated?

Comment: why PLSQL procedure? bcoz The data is handled/retrieved/managed via PLSQL packages and procedures. UI <-> Java <-> PLSQL . Its isolated  operations [serial execution]

Comment: Improving the above comment: I wrote a wrapper procedure so that now from Java, we need to call only one Stored proc. Still the time taken for STRUCT construction is more,

Comment: Ok. How is the performance of the new wrapper procedure in database when executed directly in backend? Can you post the procedure, please? And also, how are you now calling it. Before doing all that, in `SQL*Plus`, `set time on timing on` to capture the `elapsed time` for the procedure.

Comment: @LalitKumarB The time taken to execute the procedure is low, less than 90 milliseconds. The concern is not on the procedure, but over STRUCT creation and any way to bypass it. Falco has just posted the way to create Custom Java object implementing SQLData. Thanks for your time looking into this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same situation: The STRUCT Constructor is really slow, because Oracle queries the Database for attributes and a complete dependency chain, this is not only a separate DB-call, which slows you down, but also a query against some system-dictionaries.
This is somewhat implied in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html) for the STRUCT-Constructor, because *constraints and validity is tested at construction time* which is only possible by a database query for the whole object-definition.

The solution is to use a custom java-class and stream the values directly into the Procedure call, which will eliminate the constructor-time completely!

It will look like this:

```
public final class MyUserType implements SQLData
{
    public String userId;
    public String userName;

    public MyUserType(){}

    public MyUserType( final String userId, final String userName )
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException
    {
        return "one_user_type";
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL( final SQLInput stream, final String typeName ) throws SQLException
    {
        userId = stream.readString();
        userName = stream.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL( final SQLOutput stream ) throws SQLException
    {
        stream.writeString( userId );
        stream.writeString( userName );
    }
}
```

Then you just use:

```
MyUserType param = new MyUserType( "010", "Peter" );
statement.setInputParameter( 1, param );
```

Comment: Great, thanks!. I had implemented this type of custom class to read a table of objects, overriding the `readSQL()` method.
Was wondering when to override the `writeSQL()` method :).
This is the exact solution. I will modify my question and put an edit for depicting the same usecase to pass an array of objects.
This case we are setting just one object.

Comment: Can you also quote some source/reference links on your first point on STRUCT constructor?

Comment: The JDBC-Documentation is a hassle and Oracle doesn't really conform to the JDBC-Standards. I tried several approaches, also with OraData and custom descriptors and measured performance and network-traffic... I don't know if there is offical documentation about this.

Comment: @user007 I think the JavaDoc implies it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are losing a lot of time opening and closing conections, why dont you try creating a singleton connection and reusing it for every data operation.

Comment: Good point but this is not the case here. The above snippet I included involves just one connection. Get the connection, create STRUCT, call the procedure; and the time lag I am talking in when creating the STRUCT object